# Linear and continuous applications (normed space)

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces

Hello can you help me with this exercise i don't ununderstand how I must do

We provide the vectorial space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the norm 
$$
\|(x,y)\|= \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{9}}
$$
prove that $u(x,y)=\sqrt{2}x+y$ is linear and continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$

the linearity is clear but how to do for the continuity?

I must prove that 
$$
\|u\|\leq c 
$$
where $$\|u\|= \sup_{\|(x,y)\|\leq 1} \|u(x,y)\|$$ how to do?
Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't believe that function is linear. Could it be $u(x,y) = \sqrt{2} \; x + y$ instead?

Comment: you are write i don't see it clearly from 1h I will correct it

Comment: You should give more information about where you are stuck and what you have tried. Do you know how to write down the definition of linearity and continuity?

Comment: For linearity check $u(x_1,y_1)+u(x_2,y_2)=u(x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2)$. For continuity, since this is a linear functional, check if there exists a $c>0$ such that $\|u(x,y)\| \leq c \|(x,y)\|$.

Comment: I don't know how I can find $||(x,y)||$ from $||u||

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$\|u(x,y)\|=\|\sqrt{2}x+y\|=|\sqrt{2}x+y|$ (the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}$).

So try to maximize the function $f(x,y)=|\sqrt{2}x+y|$ over the elliptical region $\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{4} \leq 1$.

Comment: nothing new I write this in my question I just don't understand how I must do?

Comment: @PolineSandra you have just written symbols for the norm so it was not clear if you could interpret them to the statement I have mentioned in my response. To help you further: in order to maximize this, think for which values of $c$  will the line   $\sqrt{2}x+y=c$ be tangent to the ellipse. The tangency will help you determine the max, min values.

Comment: I don't understand why the tangent?

Comment: i found $ c= \pm \sqrt{41}$ how to contibue please

Answer (score 0):

For the continuity let $(x_n,y_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbf R^2$ such that $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$. All you have to do is to show that $$|u(x_n,y_n) - u(x,y)| = | \sqrt{2} (x_n-x) +y_n - y|\to 0, \qquad \text{for} \quad n \to +\infty.$$
**Hint:** What can you say about the convergence of the component sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ in $\mathbf R$ if you know that $(x_n,y_n)$ converges in $\mathbf R^2$? Use the triangle inequality.

Comment: we work I think with the norms